# How call static method with params using :: in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reference, static

Imagine some situation when we need to call some static method with arguments using :: in kotlin. Actually I can do it only with functions without param for example

```
Base64::hashCode
```

But when I try to use

```
Base64::encodeToString
```

Then I receive a warning that

> Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match.
> public open fun encodeToString(input: ByteArray!, flags: Int): String! defined in android.util.Base64
> public open fun encodeToString(input: ByteArray!, offset: Int, len: Int, flags: Int): String! defined in android.util.Base64

This form also aren't accepted by compiler

```
(Base64::encodeToString)( byteArrayOf(2), Base64.DEFAULT)
```

I wanted to mock this method using new feature of mockito as described [here](https://asolntsev.github.io/en/2020/07/11/mockito-static-methods/)

Thanks for any information!

Comment: Are you trying to call the method, or get a reference to it?  In Kotlin, the `::` operator is only use for the latter (so that you can pass the reference to something _else_ which will use it).  If you want to _call_ the method, you do so just as you would in Java, with e.g. `Base64.encodeToString(…)`.  Or if you want a reference, I'd expect the context to allow it to be disambiguated — if not, perhaps you could post the surrounding code?

Comment: Yes, I need a reference for that method, but I can't do it for method with multiple parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `::` syntax is very limited as it won't allow for generic type parameters and methods with multiple parameters. There is nothing stopping you however from passing a lambda reference like this:

```kotlin
{ param ->
    param.encodeToString()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adam! But where is the description of the limitation you mentioned? I tried to find this information but without success. As for using lambda, can you please explain how to pass a lambda in my case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, callable reference syntax can't be used with overloaded methods, as  compiler don't know, what variant you want him to choose (with [2](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/reference/android/util/Base64.html#encodeToString(byte%5B%5D,%20int)) or [4](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/reference/android/util/Base64.html#encodeToString(byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int)) parameters in this case).
But it is not the only problem here.

Type of the instance obtained in this manner is [KFunction](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-function/), which in parameterful case treated differently than [function types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types) (this is a well known, but still unfixed compiler [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19579)).

So, I believe you need to mock both overloaded variants of `encodeToString` method (if you want to use any of them) with the following syntax:

```kotlin
Mockito.mockStatic(Base64::class.java).use { theMock ->
    theMock.`when`<Any> { Base64.encodeToString(any(), any()) }.thenReturn("MyMockString")
    theMock.`when`<Any> { Base64.encodeToString(any(), any(), any(), any()) }.thenReturn("MyMockString")
    assertEquals("MyMockString", Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOf(), 111))
    assertEquals("MyMockString", Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOf(), 111, 111, 111))
}
```

Also note that Mockito [javadocs](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.5.13/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mockStatic-java.lang.Class-) says:

> We recommend against mocking static methods of classes in the standard library

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly specify the type, so it knows which function you want a reference to:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KFunction2

val encode: KFunction2<ByteArray, Int, ByteArray> = Base64::encode
```

where `KFunction2` means it's a 2-parameter function, and `ByteArray` and `Int` are the parameters - the last `ByteArray` is the return type.

`::encode` is a static function, so it just deals with the parameters passed in during the call. In contrast, `hashcode()` is an instance method, so even though *the call itself* doesn't take a parameter, the function takes a `Base64` instance (the thing you're calling `hashCode()` on):

```
val hashCode: KFunction1<Base64, Int> = Base64::hashCode
```

(instance type, return type)

so that's basically how it works - you can define that `encode` function reference `val` and call it as usual, and the parameter hints will show you it knows which function it is.

Can't promise it will work for whatever you're doing though!